# React typescript Types of property 'type' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've a custom button like this:

```
export enum ButtonTypes {
  'button',
  'submit',
  'reset',
  undefined,
}

type CustomButtonProps = {
    type: ButtonTypes;
};

const CustomButton: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({
    children,
    ...otherProps
}) => {
    return (
        <button className="custom-button" {...otherProps}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

In parent component:

```
<CustomButton type={ButtonTypes.submit}>
  Sign in
</CustomButton>
```

Error I get:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; type: ButtonTypes; className: string; }' is not assignable to 

type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type '{ children: ReactNode; type: ButtonTypes; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'ButtonTypes' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined'.
```

I'm quite new to typescript so may be a stupid question. However, I can't find a solution for it.

Everything compiles fine when I don't spread the props like:

```
const CustomButton: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({
    children
}, type) => {
    return (
        <button className="custom-button" type={type}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Comment: your button types are not compatible with default HTML button element types ->
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement
`HTMLButtonElement.type`
Is a DOMString indicating the behavior of the button. This is an enumerated attribute with the following possible values:
`submit`: The button submits the form. This is the default value if the attribute is not specified, or if it is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
`reset`: The button resets the form.
`button`: The button does nothing.
`menu`: The button displays a menu.

Comment: I see... But how to solve this now?

Comment: you don't need to create types for button types you can just send 'submit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use enums like you are doing, `ButtonTypes.submit` will return you a integer instead of the string `submit` and that is the type that button expects as a prop

You can define string enums and it will work fine for you. Also you need to define children prop type

```
export enum ButtonTypes {
  Button = "button",
  Submit = "submit",
  React = "reset"
}

type CustomButtonProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  type: ButtonTypes | undefined;
};
```

[**Working demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-matsumoto-0plho?file=/src/App.tsx:154-240)

Comment: Thank you!! That's it!

Comment: Glad to have helped